# Python - Multiple Clicks at different location on screen at the same time

Tags: python, mouse, pyautogui

I have this idea but I don't even know where to start haha

Basically, Lets say I want to click these 2 locations

`(50, 100) and (1000, 500)`

I could just click them 1 by 1 like this

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.click(50,100)
pyautogui.click(1000,500)
```

But what if I want to click both at the same time?

Is this possible at all?

I've heard of things such as "Multiboxing Bots" where the program is able to click on multiple places at once.

Comment: What do you consider "_at the same time_" ? do you need the clicks on the same second, millisecond or nanosecond?

Comment: Your operating system will very certainly interpret mouse clicks sequentially anyway. There is no such thing as “simultaneous mouse clicks”. Clicking “one by one” like you are doing here is probably the closest to simultaneous you can achieve.

Comment: Okay thanks for the quick replies! I mean yes it's easy to code clicks to be one by one and have all of them show the effect of "simultaneous mouse clicks" but what if now i scale this up to lets say... 100 clicks at different locations? It wouldn't be that "at the same time" would it?